# How many ways to pair tennis players?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I've come across the following problem in my textbook

[image]

I tried solving this by figuring out how many choices there are for each position within a round and came up with the following.

$${8 \choose 2} \cdot {6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot {2 \choose 2}$$

My idea was that that are ${8 \choose 2}$ ways to pick the first pair, ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to pick the second pair, etc. so multiplying them would yield all possible first round pairs, but this is not correct and I don't understand why.

**Question: Can someone please explain why the above reasoning is not correct**

Comment: This is wrong because  *a vs b, c vs d, e vs f and g vs h* is the same as *c vs d, a vs b, e vs f and g vs h*

Comment: Your way of counting makes difference between, for example, $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$, $(e,f)$, $(g,h)$, but there should be no difference.

Comment: Your way of choosing pairs overcounts things, in the sense that order matters in it. You should find a way that considers, say, ($a$ vs $b$ and $c$ vs $d$) the same as ($c$ vs $d$ and $a$ vs $b$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have missed is that a pairing like $(a,b)(c,d)(e,f)(g,h)$ is the same as $(c,d)(e,f)(a,b)(g,h)$ and any of $22$ other such permutations.  Your answer would count all $24$ of those separately.  So you need to divide your answer by $24$.

Comment: Wow, did not think of that! But this makes a lot of sense. Thanks!